# Why many people use left shift << instead of multiplication

Tags: c++

In many codes, people are using left shift to accomplish the multiplication. For example, 3 * i, some people prefer to use i << 1 + i, is there any benefit over the common one by using left shift.

Comment: Shifting is faster. Then again, a good compiler will optimize multiplication anyway.

Comment: Very few people do this, because there's no point.

Comment: These many people are either stuck in the 1980's or believe they can out-optimize the optimizing compiler. Maybe they can. Most likely they can't.

Answer (score 4):

One reason that jumps to my mind is to make the point that bitwise operations are being performed;  The code can become a lot cleaner and intentions clearer with this style of notation than using hex (matter of opinion).

For example - to make the point that the 3rd bit is being set an engineer might do

```
uint32 foo = 1 << 3;
```

Note that in this case, the compiler will optimize this away completely and replace with an assign of 0x08; but the intent of 3rd bit being set is very clear.

This has a lot of use in embedded programming, encryption and other bit specific twiddling that don't jump to my mind.

It is not for performance optimizations, since the compiler can be expected to optimize a multiply by 2 to a shift it's not any faster; and in any case you'd be unlikely to notice the gains in most applications.

Your example however,  `3*i` being replaced by `i << 1+i` is poor since they are not the same operation.

Comment: no, the example is (i << 1) + i, and they are the same thing

Comment: @zhichai Your example is `i << 1 + i`  not (i << 1) + i    The difference is that + is higher priority, and thus will be done first.

Comment: my mistake, forget to add the ()